# Adonis js adding a hosted website in cros list

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

I have a react website that i hosted in s3 as static hosting.
the URL looks like following
`http://www.<s3Buckedname>.<hosting_region>.amazonaws.com`

i website has backend which is running on my local machine url is "http://localhost:0.0.3000/". and ui hits endpoint it throws a cross origin error.

I added s3 url to cros origin in following ways.

```
  origin: "http://www.<s3Buckedname>.<hosting_region>.amazonaws.com",
  origin: ["http://www.<s3Buckedname>.<hosting_region>.amazonaws.com"],
  even tried origin :"*", origin :"*",
```

Nothing worked is there anything else i need to try to allow my local backed to use s3 bucked hosted website.

Please help,
Thanks in advance.